# Is there a standard way for .NET class loaders to work?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, classloader, static-constructor

Is there a standard way for .NET class loaders to work?

Say I compile this code:

```
Option Strict On : Option Explicit On

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Main")
        Dim g = C.A
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class C
    Shared Sub New()
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Init C")
    End Sub
    Shared Property A As New A
End Class

Public Class A
    Shared Sub New()
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Init A")
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("A Constructor")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can I guarantee the compiled code will (in all implemented platforms) have the following output?

```
Main
Init A
A Constructor
Init C
```

Comment: "Class loader" means something else.  You are talking about a "class initializer", aka "static constructor".

Comment: Jon Skeet discusses type initialization (with some .NET 4 changes) here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx

Comment: @Hans: Perhaps, but it's also reasonable to wonder whether the runtime class loader is guaranteed to call the *type initializer* at a specific time. (In fact, it's legal for the class loader to do so only for types marked `beforefieldinit`, otherwise the *type initializer* must be called at a later time as indicated by the spec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using constructors and not inline initialization, the VB compiler does not mark the types with `beforefieldinit`, and the order is exactly controlled.

If, however, you wrote the following (using inline initialization):

```
Option Strict On : Option Explicit On

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        System.Console.WriteLine("Main")
        Dim g = C.A
    End Sub
End Module
Public Class C
    Shared Function Narg() As A
        Dim alpha As New A
        System.Console.WriteLine("Init C")
        Return alpha
    End Function
    Shared Property A As A = Narg()
End Class
Public Class A
    Shared Sub New()
        System.Console.WriteLine("Init A")
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
        System.Console.WriteLine("A Constructor")
    End Sub
End Class
```

the order would be unspecified.  The same order as your original code would be allowed, but `C` can be initialized earlier.  In fact, on my system the output is:

```
Init A
A Constructor
Init C
Main
```

The reason is that `C` now is marked `beforefieldinit`.

---

Gratuitous nit-picking: No, your original code is not guaranteed to have that output.  On a release build it will have no output, because `System.Diagnostics.Debug` is conditionally called.

Comment: I don’t understand how this output is legal: an instance of `A` is created via `New` immediately *before* the `Init C` output is made. Is the optimizer reordering instructions? Why is it allowed to, here? This has got nothing to do with initialisation order (!), we simply have two adjacent statements with side-effects.

Comment: @Konrad: `beforefieldinit` allows the `C` initializer to run at any time before `C.A` is used.  So in this case it actually runs before `Main`.  The `Init A - A Constructor - Init C` order hasn't changed (and can't).  A new A is constructed in `Narg()`, which calls `A Constructor`.  But `A Constructor` can't run until the initializer for `A` runs, so the JIT runs that first.  After `A Constructor` returns, `Narg()` continues running and prints `Init C`.  This gives rise to the subsequence mentioned.

Comment: So far so good. But then the constructor of `A` *also* needs to run before `Main`, because it’s invoked inside the initialiser, before the console output `"Init C"`.

Comment: @Konrad: The constructor of `A` did run before `Main`, although this is not guaranteed.  It's only guaranteed that it runs before the line `Init C` is printed, which is allowed by `beforefieldinit` to be either right after `Main` is printed, or any time earlier.

Comment: Ah, I see. I simply misread your output somehow and thought `Init C` was standing *before `A Constructor`. My mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the order of calling static and instance constructors is part of the language specification. All conforming compilers should emit the same IL for this program.

Comment: At the same time, "the same IL" leaves the runtime with some leeway as to exactly when the type initializers run, especially when `beforefieldinit` is used.